# How to get null value from stored procedure out parameter using php mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

I am using the following code to bind out parameter for stored procedure.

```
mssql_bind($stmt, '@_SORef', $Ref, SQLVARCHAR, true);
```

But, I am getting empty value instead of null as value of $Ref. How can I get null value from the out parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the optional is_null parameter

```
mssql_bind($stmt, '@_SORef', $Ref, SQLVARCHAR, true, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php